# Unable to parse debug msg in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have got a debug msg in ansible in the below format:

```
"msg": [
    "Output:                   test output   ",
    "ABC:                           some text   ",
    "",
    "Master         ",
    "Location:   test location ",
    "URL:        https://www.google.com   "
]
```

}

Now I want to retrieve the URL value from the above output, which i will use in rest of the ansible script. How can i get this URL which is "http://www.google.com", in this exact format? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**How can I get this URL which is "http://www.google.com", in this exact format?**"*

A: Create a dictionary. Given the list

```yaml
    my_list:
      ["Output:                   test output   ",
      "ABC:                           some text   ",
      "",
      "Master         ",
      "Location:   test location ",
      "URL:        https://www.google.com   "]
```

The task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_dict: "{{ my_dict|default({})|combine(item|from_yaml) }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
      when: item|from_yaml is mapping
```

creates the dictionary

```yaml
  my_dict:
    ABC: some text
    Location: test location
    Output: test output
    URL: https://www.google.com
```

Get the attribute *URL*

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_dict.URL
```

gives

```yaml
  my_dict.URL: https://www.google.com
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works perfectly.